# Closure over an SSH session - is this possible?

Tags: session, ssh, clojure, closures

What I am trying to do is to issue command over SSH repeatedly.  This works just fine if I do the following:

```clojure
(ns bla
  (:require [clj-ssh.ssh :as ssh]))

(defn poll [func]
  (while true
    (func)
    (Thread/sleep 1000)))

(defn exec-on-ssh
  "Connects to a host and then does there whatever the passed command dictates"
  [host command]
  (let [agent (ssh/ssh-agent {})
        session (ssh/session agent host {:strict-host-key-checking :no})]
    (ssh/with-connection session
      (poll (fn [] (let [result (ssh/ssh session {:cmd command})]
                     (println (get result :out))))))))

; usage:
(exec-on-ssh "some-host" "uptime | sed s/^.*average:\\ //")
```

But then I had the bright idea of returning a function instead, to which I just pass the command and the processing function:

```clojure
(defn exec-on-ssh
  "Connects to a host and then does there whatever the passed command dictates"
  [host]
  (let [agent (ssh/ssh-agent {})
        session (ssh/session agent host {:strict-host-key-checking :no})]
    (ssh/with-connection session
      (fn [command process-fun] 
        (while true 
          (let [result (ssh/ssh session {:cmd command})]
            (process-fun (get result :out))))))))

; usage:
((exec-on-ssh "some-host") "uptime | sed s/^.*average:\\ //" println)
```

But this throws the following exception:

```
JSchException Packet corrupt  com.jcraft.jsch.Session.start_discard (Session.java:1050)
```

If I understand this correctly, it happens because by the time it would execute anything, the session is already gone.  After experimenting a bit, it looks like this happens because of the closure over `ssh/ssh`.

Is there a way to keep the session *and* to have the flexibility the second approach offers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried moving `with-connection` call inside the `fn`?

Also this is probably not specific to SSH in any way. Try writing some code that builds and returns a function within a `with-open` block, the file will be closed at the moment `with-open` is exited.

What I am trying to draw attention to is the difference between `let` bindings and `with-*` block. The latter is about resources and they close the resource after their body is executed. So in your specific example, you create a resource object, you successfully create with function closing over this object. Then the resource, well connection here, is closed. The function still has a reference to it. It is just not open anymore.

Comment: Yeah, it is my sillyness - I was not returning the function I expected to return.  With the change you suggest it works.